# Why this errot coming on page refreshing in acumatica. {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

SELECT [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[UserID] AS [MUIUserScreenRelevance_UserID], [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[NodeID] AS [MUIUserScreenRelevance_NodeID], [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[Relevance] AS [MUIUserScreenRelevance_Relevance]
FROM [MUIUserScreenRelevance] [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance]
WHERE [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[UserID] = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'b5344897-037e-4d58-b5c3-1bdfd0f47bf9') AND ( [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[CompanyID] = 2)
ORDER BY [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[UserID], [r_MUIUserScreenRelevance].[NodeID] OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)

at Serilog.Core.Logger.Write(LogEventLevel level, Exception exception, String messageTemplate, Object[] propertyValues)
at Serilog.Core.Logger.Information[T](String messageTemplate, T propertyValue)

Comment: This look like an information message. On left side of traces, is that item tagged as error or information?

Answer (score 0):

An error has occurred during your processing. You need to review the Trace log and most likely will find the error on one of the trace items. Alternatively, switch on the Request Profiler and reprocess what you tried on the above. What changes were made that caused this - I find retracing your steps on each change made backwards will point you in the right direction.